# Doesn't google execute javascript if I add <meta name="fragment" content="!"> in html?

Tags: seo, search-engine-bots, angular-seo

I have built site with angularjs and I am using html5 pushstate mode.
I have also added   tag in html page.
I don't provide html snapshots for bots. I am expecting google to execute javascript itself and index my site. But, google is indexing the html page as it is(without executing javascript.).
I am not in mood of providing html snapshots because,I've read that google executes javascript well. I have added above meta tag for googlebot to tell to execute javascript. But Is it expecting snapshot because I have added   meta tag?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar discussion over at WMC that may help you...

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/c-JP9z6Xwd4;context-place=mydiscussions